# How to run multiple asyncio loops inside syncrhonous sub-processes inside a main asyncio loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, process-pool

I have a main function which I run with `asyncio` and then inside it I used `event_loop.run_in_executor()` to run mutliple processes of a blocking function.

What I wish to do is inside each of these processes to run a new asyncio loop for each one in order to execute async code.

So I have a main async function where I create multiple processes and I want to create a new asyncio loop in each of them. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just call `asyncio.run` within your subprocess with a coroutine with the async work you want to do. A minimal example that spins up 5 processes each with their own event loops:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def run_loop_in_process():
    async def subprocess_async_work():
        await asyncio.sleep(5) #whatever async code you need
    asyncio.run(subprocess_async_work())

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(pool, run_loop_in_process) for _ in range(5)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: so you can call asyncio.run() within asyncio.run() ?

Comment: @KZiovas yes, since you're calling it within a separate subprocess you'll get a new event loop so it is safe. Do keep in mind that two event loops in the same process will cause problems.

Comment: i tested it does work, one thing I had to change was various object `self.variable` that I was reusing in the functions that I wanted to run in the sub-processes. I had to re-declare the variables in each sub-process because they were trying to use the same resources (some client objects). But that is to be expected.